# Can I match speaker with pitch, timbre and volume?

Tags: audio, machine-learning, deep-learning

I want to make a speaker recognition system. I don’t want to make it using deep learning as perhaps it will require a lot of data. Can I implement it using audio components mentioned above or more?

Answer (score 1):

In all case, you will need data learning if you want to "recognize" speakers. A classical approach is based on [MFCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum) computation and a classification by [kMeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) (or more elaborate [GMMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model)).

You'll find [here](http://www-lium.univ-lemans.fr/diarization/doku.php/overview) an overview of the full system of the LIUM for speaker diarization (which is more sophisticated).